# Can I use a Windows 8.1 API in Windows Embedded 8 Standard?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-embedded-compact, windows-embedded, windows-embedded-standard

I am trying to make an embedded music device.

There is already an existing music API I would like to use which has support for Windows 8.1 (*not* embedded). I am trying to figure out if there is a way for me to leverage the existing 8.1 music API with what Windows offers in its embedded solutions. Because it is a music device, it needs to be as real-time as possible. I realize there is the Windows Embedded Compact edition, but I don't believe I would be able to use a Windows 8.1 SDK in this environment. Am I right?

- Would I be able to use the 8.1 music API in a Windows 8.1 Embedded Standard environment?
- How responsive would the Embedded Standard environment be to different events that are occurring in the device?
- Is there any real-time Standard Environment extension?
- Is there any way I can use the music Windows 8.1 API inside a Windows 10 IOT environment?

Comment: On SO, it is generally one question per post, possibly two if related. I would advise narrowing down your question :)

Comment: My apologies. I will do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little bit more research myself, and IntervalZero (intervalzero.com) turns windows operating systems into realtime operating systems. So, it appears like I will actually be able to use the music windows API with one of Windows embedded OSs and add on RTX (from Interval Zero) to make the music embedded system real time and thus suitable for my needs.

I am going to look some more into how to use a Windows 8 API in Windows 10 IOT. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. According to what I see in Microsoft's documentation, you can only use API's in Embedded Industry.
2. It depends on the device. If the device specs can handle those events, it would be responsive.
3. I can not find one.
4. You should be able to.